# numpy code works in REPL, script says type error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Copy and pasting this code into the `python3` REPL works, but when I run it as a script, I get a type error.

```
"""Softmax."""

scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]

import numpy as np
from math import e

def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    results = []
    x = np.transpose(x)
    for j in range(len(x)):
        exps = [np.exp(s) for s in x[j]]
        _sum = np.sum(np.exp(x[j]))
        softmax = [i / _sum for i in exps]
        results.append(softmax)
    final = np.vstack(results)
    return np.transpose(final)
#    pass  # TODO: Compute and return softmax(x)


print(softmax(scores))

# Plot softmax curves
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])

plt.plot(x, softmax(scores).T, linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

The error I get running the script via CLI is the following:

```
bash$ python3 softmax.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "softmax.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(softmax(scores))
  File "softmax.py", line 13, in softmax
    exps = [np.exp(s) for s in x[j]]
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

This kind of crap makes me so nervous about running interpreted code in production with libraries like these, seriously unreliable and undefined behaviour is totally unacceptable IMO.

Comment: So if nobody knows the answer to this question I'm going to assume that numpy ecosystems is close to garbage and shouldn't be let anywhere near a production application.

Comment: Please try to print `x[j]` What is there? seems like you have number but you want to iterate over it.

Comment: Dude, it works in a REPL, you can copy paste it yourself. That's probably not the issue. And it's a giant array anyways.

Comment: `exps = np.exp(x)` or, if you do not like _ufuncs_, `exps = [np.exp(s) for s in x]`.  And no, when I've checked in the interpreter I wasn't lucky and a `TypeError` was raised instead.

Comment: Dude, no it does not. I have checked both REPLs: `python` native one and `ipython`

Comment: You didn't mention what python version. I used 3. I'm assuming you used whatever was your default.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your script, you define

```
scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]
```

This is the argument in your first call of `softmax(scores)`.  When converted to a numpy array, `scores` is 1-d array with shape (3,).
You pass `scores` into the function, and then it is converted to a numpy array by the call

```
    x = np.transpose(x)
```

However, it is still 1-d, with shape (3,).  The [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function swaps dimensions, but it does not add a dimension to a 1-d array.  In effect, `transpose` is a "no-op" when applied to a 1-d array.

Then, in the loop that follows, `x[j]` is a scalar of type `numpy.float64`, so it does not make sense to write `[np.exp(s) for s in x[j]]`.  `x[j]` is a scalar, not a sequence, so you can't iterate over it.

In the bottom part of your script, you redefine `scores` as

```
x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])
```

Now `scores` is 2-d array (`scores.shape` is (3, 80)), so you don't get an error when you call `softmax(scores)`.